# Catching ftp exception in Talend and retrying

Tags: talend

I have a Talend job where i am making a ftp connection and downloading a file. I wanted to add capability where if the ftphost is not responding i can retry connecting n times before killing the job. I looked at lLogCatcher and tLoop but that doesn't seem to serve the purpose. Any pointers on which direction i should take would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To catch Exception, you can use a tJavaFlex containing a try and catch, then by playing with conditions you can use tLoop, I have developed this small job because i love challenging, and its works fine
[image]

1. We need 2 context variable:

   - trynb : int ( max tries number )
   - isitok : int (default 0, we will use it later )
2. tLoop settings, use while type:

[image]

3. tJava_1: its just to generate different ip so i can perform the test, you can remove it for your case.
4. tJavaFlex: to catch Exception, write `try{` in start code box and `}catch(Exception e){System.out.println("to the next try ");}` in the end code box. You MUST use iterate to connect the next component.
5. tFTPConnection: your FTP settings.
6. tJava_2: if tFTPConnection is ok, we need to make tLoop break looping by altering the context variable, write this line:
   `context.isitok=1;`
7. tJava_3: just to ensure orchestration, it have no code.
8. If (order:1) : `((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION")) < context.trynb`
9. If (order:2) : `((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION")) >= context.trynb`

Comment: This solution is very well written and gives me an idea on how to approach this issue. Thank you very much for your time and suggestion.